# Using factor function to get rid of Xs in front of values and set the labels

Tags: r, long-format-data

The years in the Year column have Xs in front of them. I would like to get rid of these, using the “factor” function and set the labels. How can i do this please?

[image]

The reason why i do this is to make my graph look prettier.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
trendsdata <- structure(list(Year = c("X2015", "X2015", "X2015", "X2015", "X2015", 
                        "X2015")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
#--------------
trendsdata$Year <- trendsdata$Year |> str_sub(2, 5) |>
  factor(labels = "First Year")
levels(trendsdata$Year)
    [1] "First Year"
```

Using str_sub to strip out the X, and factor to set the levels.
I suspect that you will be happy without setting labels, in which case, just delete `labels = "First Year"`